# How can I resolve the error 'Data truncation: Out of range value for column 'id_brand' at row 1'?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, javafx

I'm working on a Java project with FX and SQL. In this Java project I have a store where I can add products to the database.

Now I also want that I can update a product. I can only update the price of the product but not the brand name and type name. When I want to update the brand name or the type name I receive an error in the console.

[image]

This is the code to update a product:

```
 public int editProduct(Double price, int brand, int type,  int id) {
    String sql = "UPDATE products SET price=?, id_brand=?, id_type=? WHERE id=?";
    try {
        Class.forName(DRIVER);
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);
        PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        stmt.setDouble(1, price);
        stmt.setInt(2, brand);
        stmt.setInt(3, type);
        stmt.setInt(4, id);
        int rows = stmt.executeUpdate();
        getProducts();
        con.close();
        return rows;
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex) {
        System.out.println("SQL error updaten product");
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
    return -1;
}
```

-

```
    public class EditProductController {

    @FXML TextField productId, productBrand, productType, productPrice;
    @FXML Label berichtMelding;
    @FXML Button saveButton;

    private StoreDataAccesObject storeDDA;

    public void fill (Product data) {
        berichtMelding.setText(Integer.toString(data.getId()));

        productType.setText(data.getType());
        productBrand.setText(data.getBrand());
        productPrice.setText(Double.toString(data.getPrice()));
    }

    public void updateProductButton() {
        storeDDA = new StoreDataAccesObject("noorderpoort", "toets");

        ArrayList<String> errorList = new ArrayList<>();
        String brand = productBrand.getText();
        String type = productType.getText();
        String price = productPrice.getText();
        String id = berichtMelding.getText();

        int idBrand;
        int idType;

        if (brand.trim().length() <= 0 || type.trim().length() <= 0 || price.trim().length() <= 0) {
            errorList.add("Alle velden moeten ingevuld zijn.");
        } else {

            if (storeDDA.nameExists("brands", brand) > 0) { //checking if brand exists in database.
                idBrand = storeDDA.nameExists("brands", brand);
            } else {
                idBrand = storeDDA.nameExists("brands", brand);
                if (idBrand < 0) {
                    errorList.add("Brand niet opgeslagen");
                }
            }

            if (storeDDA.nameExists("types", type) > 0) {
                idType = storeDDA.nameExists("types", type);
            } else {
                idType = storeDDA.nameExists("types", type);
                if (idType < 0) {
                    errorList.add("Type niet opgeslagen");
                }
            }

            if (storeDDA.editProduct(Double.parseDouble(price), idBrand, idType, Integer.parseInt(id)) <= 0) {
                berichtMelding.setText("Product niet geupdate.");
            } else {
                Stage editProduct = (Stage) saveButton.getScene().getWindow();
                editProduct.close();
            }
        }

        if (!errorList.isEmpty()) {
            String errorText = "";
            for (String error : errorList) {
                errorText += error;
            }
            berichtMelding.setText(errorText);
        }
    }
}
```

Tables:

[image]

Comment: Describe your tables.

Comment: I have added a photo of the tables @nnn

Comment: And what value are you trying to pass in id_brand?

Comment: For example, the brand is called 'Samsung' and I want to change it to 'LG'. Then that error appears when I press the button to let it change it to 'LG' @NaveenArora

Comment: Naveen asked what value? That row can take only integers not strings.

Comment: Yes right, and also the problem is not with brand name, it is with id_brand. May be you are trying to update some value in id_brand.

Comment: [mcve] please .. and no screenshots of text

Comment: Don't use "String" and "Text" functions to manipulate numeric values.  Fix the app code.

Answer (score 0):

> 'Data truncation: Out of range value for column 'id_brand' at row 1'?

The data you are trying to store in `id_brand` does not fit. For example, string might be too long or number too large.

Check the value of unsigned `id_brand` column if it meets the range.

Answer (score 0):

You have defined the length of id_brand column as 11 and i think you are trying to add value with length more than 11. I reproduced the same error at my end.

```
create table Test(id integer(11) unsigned);
insert into Test values(1234567891011);
Error:Out of range value for column 'id'ar row 1
```

And if you are trying to add String value in Integer column then it will not throw the above mentioned error instead it will show:

```
Incorrect integer value: 'A' for column 'id' at row 1
```

Comment: I replaced it with text. Thanks.